# Avoiding repetitive lines with php

Tags: php

I am trying to make a dico checking. So when a user writes a word, the code will find the first letter and check from the correspondent table. I splitted the dictionary into 26 tables.
The code is functioning but the code is awful, too much repetition.
I know there is some way to reduce all that code.
So... Any suggestions?

```
<?php
$lng=strlen($word);$cr=0;
$f1='<div class="fOne">Votre mot : '.$word.' ( <b>'.$lng.'</b> Lettres )';
$f2='<div class="fTwo">Votre mot : '.$word.' ( <b>'.$lng.'</b> Lettres )';
$f3='<div class="fThree">********** ( '.$lng.' Lettres )';
     if ($lng>0) 
        {
         include "../config.php";
if($lng==10) {
if (mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT mot FROM dix WHERE mot='$word'",$conn))>0) echo $f1.' est correct ! <br>';
else {echo $f2.' est incorrect !<br>';$cr=1;}
} else {
         switch ($word[0])
            {
             case 'A':if (mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT mot FROM adiki WHERE mot='$word'",$conn))>0) echo $f1.' est correct ! <br>'; else {echo $f2.' est incorrect !<br>';$cr=1;} break;
             case 'B':if (mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT mot FROM bdiki WHERE mot='$word'",$conn))>0) echo $f1.' est correct ! <br>'; else {echo $f2.' est incorrect !<br>';$cr=1;} break;
             case 'C':if (mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT mot FROM cdiki WHERE mot='$word'",$conn))>0) echo $f1.' est correct ! <br>'; else {echo $f2.' est incorrect !<br>';$cr=1;} break;
             case 'D':if (mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT mot FROM ddiki WHERE mot='$word'",$conn))>0) echo $f1.' est correct ! <br>'; else {echo $f2.' est incorrect !<br>';$cr=1;} break;
             case 'E':if (mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT mot FROM ediki WHERE mot='$word'",$conn))>0) echo $f1.' est correct ! <br>'; else {echo $f2.' est incorrect !<br>';$cr=1;} break;
             case 'F':if (mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT mot FROM fdiki WHERE mot='$word'",$conn))>0) echo $f1.' est correct ! <br>'; else {echo $f2.' est incorrect !<br>';$cr=1;} break;
             case 'G':if (mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT mot FROM gdiki WHERE mot='$word'",$conn))>0) echo $f1.' est correct ! <br>'; else {echo $f2.' est incorrect !<br>';$cr=1;} break;
             case 'H':if (mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT mot FROM hdiki WHERE mot='$word'",$conn))>0) echo $f1.' est correct ! <br>'; else {echo $f2.' est incorrect !<br>';$cr=1;} break;
             case 'I':if (mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT mot FROM idiki WHERE mot='$word'",$conn))>0) echo $f1.' est correct ! <br>'; else {echo $f2.' est incorrect !<br>';$cr=1;} break;
             case 'J':if (mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT mot FROM jdiki WHERE mot='$word'",$conn))>0) echo $f1.' est correct ! <br>'; else {echo $f2.' est incorrect !<br>';$cr=1;} break;
             case 'K':if (mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT mot FROM kdiki WHERE mot='$word'",$conn))>0) echo $f1.' est correct ! <br>'; else {echo $f2.' est incorrect !<br>';$cr=1;} break;
             case 'L':if (mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT mot FROM ldiki WHERE mot='$word'",$conn))>0) echo $f1.' est correct ! <br>'; else {echo $f2.' est incorrect !<br>';$cr=1;} break;
             case 'M':if (mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT mot FROM mdiki WHERE mot='$word'",$conn))>0) echo $f1.' est correct ! <br>'; else {echo $f2.' est incorrect !<br>';$cr=1;} break;
             case 'N':if (mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT mot FROM ndiki WHERE mot='$word'",$conn))>0) echo $f1.' est correct ! <br>'; else {echo $f2.' est incorrect !<br>';$cr=1;} break;
             case 'O':if (mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT mot FROM odiki WHERE mot='$word'",$conn))>0) echo $f1.' est correct ! <br>'; else {echo $f2.' est incorrect !<br>';$cr=1;} break;
             case 'P':if (mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT mot FROM pdiki WHERE mot='$word'",$conn))>0) echo $f1.' est correct ! <br>'; else {echo $f2.' est incorrect !<br>';$cr=1;} break;
             case 'Q':if (mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT mot FROM qdiki WHERE mot='$word'",$conn))>0) echo $f1.' est correct ! <br>'; else {echo $f2.' est incorrect !<br>';$cr=1;} break;
             case 'R':if (mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT mot FROM rdiki WHERE mot='$word'",$conn))>0) echo $f1.' est correct ! <br>'; else {echo $f2.' est incorrect !<br>';$cr=1;} break;
             case 'S':if (mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT mot FROM sdiki WHERE mot='$word'",$conn))>0) echo $f1.' est correct ! <br>'; else {echo $f2.' est incorrect !<br>';$cr=1;} break;
             case 'T':if (mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT mot FROM tdiki WHERE mot='$word'",$conn))>0) echo $f1.' est correct ! <br>'; else {echo $f2.' est incorrect !<br>';$cr=1;} break;
             case 'U':if (mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT mot FROM udiki WHERE mot='$word'",$conn))>0) echo $f1.' est correct ! <br>'; else {echo $f2.' est incorrect !<br>';$cr=1;} break;
             case 'V':if (mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT mot FROM vdiki WHERE mot='$word'",$conn))>0) echo $f1.' est correct ! <br>'; else {echo $f2.' est incorrect !<br>';$cr=1;} break;
             case 'W':if (mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT mot FROM wdiki WHERE mot='$word'",$conn))>0) echo $f1.' est correct ! <br>'; else {echo $f2.' est incorrect !<br>';$cr=1;} break;
             case 'X':if (mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT mot FROM xdiki WHERE mot='$word'",$conn))>0) echo $f1.' est correct ! <br>'; else {echo $f2.' est incorrect !<br>';$cr=1;} break;
             case 'Y':if (mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT mot FROM ydiki WHERE mot='$word'",$conn))>0) echo $f1.' est correct ! <br>'; else {echo $f2.' est incorrect !<br>';$cr=1;} break;
             case 'Z':if (mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT mot FROM zdiki WHERE mot='$word'",$conn))>0) echo $f1.' est correct ! <br>'; else {echo $f2.' est incorrect !<br>';$cr=1;} break;
            }
                        }
        }
    else {$cr=1;echo $f3.' - Pas de mot !';}
 ?>
```

Comment: This code is Unreadable.

Comment: all your if conditions differ by one letter. Why do you duplicate whole string for one letter ?

Comment: Switch 'The first letter of the word entered by user', if it's 'A', the cpu will go to table Adiki where all words that begin with 'A' are stored.

Comment: If you want to improve your working codes, go to codereview.stackexchange.com. Here we deal with only problems.

Comment: It's not really clear what you want. But if you want an autocomplete function, there is one in jQueryUI: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: @SergioIvanuzzo : because I didn't find how to make it shorter! The condition changes and the table changes.

Comment: You shoul create a function checkInDb() and pass it the table name. In the function put the query and return simply true or false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
    $firstletter = strtolower($word[0]); //making it lowercase
    if(ctype_alnum($firstletter)) { //checking if it's a letter and nothing else
        $sql = "SELECT mot FROM {$firstletter}diki WHERE mot='$word'";
        if (mysql_num_rows(mysql_query($sql,$conn))>0) { 
            echo $f1.' est correct ! <br>'; 
        } 
        else { 
            echo $f2.' est incorrect !<br>'; 
            //what ever else you need here
        }
    } else {
        echo('First character is not a letter.');
    }
?>
```